# Error "DUPLICATE_DECLARATIVE_COLUMN_INFO" while connecting Quicksight to AWS Catalog via Athena

Tags: aws-glue, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight, data-connections

I am trying to connect Quicksight to AWS Catalog via Athena and upon selecting the database and the required table, i am getting an error saying "DUPLICATE_DECLARATIVE_COLUMN_INFO" though there is no duplicate columns.
I am able to connect to it when I am using Custom SQL.

It should give me the table data as expected but it didn't.

Comment: Custom SQL as in "Select * From Table"?

Comment: Yes, while doing it this way, it works but not directly